# Accelerate the use of MPI types

Tags: fortran, gpu, mpi, openacc, pgi-accelerator

I have a Fortran program that uses MPI types to describe subarrays for data transfers, which prevents me to create send/receive buffers manually. This works nice, but when accelerating the program with OpenACC, the subarrays may be not contiguous in memory, and may require more or less time to be copied from the GPU memory.

Here is a (rather long) minimal example of two cubic domains of `n**3` elements exchanging one face with each other (domain 0 sends face `n` - 1 and receives face `n`, domain 1 sends face 2 and receives face 1). The face to use is either i, j, or k, and must be set at compile time with either `-DORDER_I`, `-DORDER_J`, or `-DORDER_K`. Subarray MPI types are created with `mpi_type_create_subarray` and data are exchanged with `mpi_sendrecv`:

```
#if defined(ORDER_I)
#define SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(size) [size, elements, elements]
#define SUBARRAY_INDEX(index) [index, 0, 0]
#define ARRAY(array, dim, other) array(dim, other, other)
#elif defined(ORDER_J)
#define SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(size) [elements, size, elements]
#define SUBARRAY_INDEX(index) [0, index, 0]
#define ARRAY(array, dim, other) array(other, dim, other)
#elif defined(ORDER_K)
#define SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(size) [elements, elements, size]
#define SUBARRAY_INDEX(index) [0, 0, index]
#define ARRAY(array, dim, other) array(other, other, dim)
#else
#error "Define ORDER_I, ORDER_J, or ORDER_K"
#endif

#ifndef ELEMENTS
#define ELEMENTS 100
#endif

#ifndef ITERATIONS
#define ITERATIONS 10
#endif

program test
    use mpi
    use openacc

    implicit none

    integer, allocatable :: array(:, :, :)
    integer, parameter :: elements = ELEMENTS
    integer, parameter :: iterations = ITERATIONS
    integer :: ierror
    integer :: rank, rank_other
    integer :: recv_index, send_index
    integer :: recv_type, send_type
    integer :: gpu_device, n_gpu
    integer :: k, i

    call mpi_init(ierror)
    call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)

    ! assign GPU to MPI rank
    gpu_device = acc_get_device_type()
    n_gpu = acc_get_num_devices(gpu_device)
    call acc_set_device_num(mod(rank, n_gpu), gpu_device)

    ! set parameters according to MPI rank
    if (rank == 0) then
        rank_other = 1
        send_index = elements - 1
        recv_index = elements
    else
        rank_other = 0
        send_index = 2
        recv_index = 1
    end if

    ! create mpi types
    call mpi_type_create_subarray( &
        3, &
        [elements, elements, elements], &
        SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(1), &
        SUBARRAY_INDEX(send_index - 1), &
        MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, &
        MPI_INTEGER, &
        send_type, &
        ierror &
    )
    call mpi_type_commit(send_type, ierror)
    call mpi_type_create_subarray( &
        3, &
        [elements, elements, elements], &
        SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(1), &
        SUBARRAY_INDEX(recv_index - 1), &
        MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, &
        MPI_INTEGER, &
        recv_type, &
        ierror &
    )
    call mpi_type_commit(recv_type, ierror)

    ! create arrays
    allocate(array(elements, elements, elements))

    !$acc data copyout(array)

    !$acc kernels loop independent
    do i = 1, elements
        ARRAY(array, i, :) = rank * 1000 + i
    end do
    !$acc end kernels

    !$acc host_data use_device(array)

    do k = 1, iterations
        !$acc kernels
        array(:, :, :) = array(:, :, :) + 1
        !$acc end kernels

        ! transfer data
        call mpi_sendrecv( &
            array, &
            1, &
            send_type, &
            rank_other, &
            10, &
            array, &
            1, &
            recv_type, &
            rank_other, &
            10, &
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
            MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, &
            ierror &
        )

    end do

    !$acc end host_data

    !$acc end data

    ! print outcome
    print "(i0, ':', 2(x, i5), ' ...', 2(x, i5))", rank, ARRAY(array, 1:2, 1), ARRAY(array, elements-1:elements, 1)

    deallocate(array)

    call mpi_finalize(ierror)
end program
```

Compiled with NVHPC SDK 22.7 and executed on 2 NVIDIA P100 GPUs, the code shows that memory copy times differ significantly: the worst being order i (86 % of time spent in copying), then order j (6 %), then order k (less than 1 %). This makes sense, as a k face would be contiguous in memory. Visualizing the different performance on NVIDIA Nsight Systems gives:

[image: performance with MPI type]

The graph shows the memory operations sandwiched between two dummy computations.

I suppose using MPI types implies the creation of buffers under the hood. Unfortunately, the way the buffers are created is not optimal as many operations may be made from and to the GPU memory.

Rewriting the example with manual buffer creation, the code becomes:

```
#if defined(ORDER_I)
#define SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(size) [size, elements, elements]
#define SUBARRAY_INDEX(index) [index, 0, 0]
#define ARRAY(array, dim, other) array(dim, other, other)
#define ARRAY2(array, dim, other1, other2) array(dim, other1, other2)
#elif defined(ORDER_J)
#define SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(size) [elements, size, elements]
#define SUBARRAY_INDEX(index) [0, index, 0]
#define ARRAY(array, dim, other) array(other, dim, other)
#define ARRAY2(array, dim, other1, other2) array(other1, dim, other2)
#elif defined(ORDER_K)
#define SUBARRAY_ELEMENTS(size) [elements, elements, size]
#define SUBARRAY_INDEX(index) [0, 0, index]
#define ARRAY(array, dim, other) array(other, other, dim)
#define ARRAY2(array, dim, other1, other2) array(other1, other2, dim)
#else
#error "Define ORDER_I, ORDER_J, or ORDER_K"
#endif

#ifndef ELEMENTS
#define ELEMENTS 100
#endif

#ifndef ITERATIONS
#define ITERATIONS 10
#endif

program test
    use mpi
    use openacc

    implicit none

    integer, allocatable :: array(:, :, :)
    integer, allocatable :: send_buffer(:), recv_buffer(:)
    integer, parameter :: elements = ELEMENTS
    integer, parameter :: iterations = ITERATIONS
    integer :: ierror
    integer :: rank, rank_other
    integer :: recv_index, send_index
    integer :: gpu_device, n_gpu
    integer :: k, i, j

    call mpi_init(ierror)
    call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)

    ! assign GPU to MPI rank
    gpu_device = acc_get_device_type()
    n_gpu = acc_get_num_devices(gpu_device)
    call acc_set_device_num(mod(rank, n_gpu), gpu_device)

    ! set parameters according to MPI rank
    if (rank == 0) then
        rank_other = 1
        send_index = elements - 1
        recv_index = elements
    else
        rank_other = 0
        send_index = 2
        recv_index = 1
    end if

    ! create arrays
    allocate(array(elements, elements, elements))
    allocate(send_buffer(elements * elements))
    allocate(recv_buffer(elements * elements))

    !$acc data copyout(array) copyout(send_buffer, recv_buffer)

    !$acc kernels loop independent
    do i = 1, elements
        ARRAY(array, i, :) = rank * 1000 + i
    end do
    !$acc end kernels

    !$acc host_data use_device(send_buffer, recv_buffer)

    do k = 1, iterations
        !$acc kernels
        array(:, :, :) = array(:, :, :) + 1
        !$acc end kernels

        ! data to buffer
        !$acc kernels loop independent collapse(2)
        do j = 1, elements
            do i = 1, elements
                send_buffer((j - 1) * elements + i) = ARRAY2(array, send_index, i, j)
            end do
        end do
        !$acc end kernels

        ! transfer data
        call mpi_sendrecv( &
            send_buffer, &
            size(send_buffer), &
            MPI_INTEGER, &
            rank_other, &
            10, &
            recv_buffer, &
            size(recv_buffer), &
            MPI_INTEGER, &
            rank_other, &
            10, &
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
            MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, &
            ierror &
        )

        ! buffer to data
        !$acc kernels loop independent collapse(2)
        do j = 1, elements
            do i = 1, elements
                ARRAY2(array, recv_index, i, j) = recv_buffer((j - 1) * elements + i)
            end do
        end do
        !$acc end kernels

    end do

    !$acc end host_data

    !$acc end data

    ! print outcome
    print "(i0, ':', 2(x, i5), ' ...', 2(x, i5))", rank, ARRAY(array, 1:2, 1), ARRAY(array, elements-1:elements, 1)

    deallocate(array)

    call mpi_finalize(ierror)
end program
```

Executed in the same environment, for any face used, time spend in copying is almost the same (less than 1 %):

[image: performance with manual buffer]

So my question is, is there a way to accelerate the use of MPI types (first code)?

Comment: Some MPI implementations claim to be "gpu aware". You probably need that.

Comment: The OpenMPI implementation shipped with NVHPC SDK 22.7 is the version 3.1.5. OpenMPI is supposed to be GPU aware since version 1.7.0. I could not use `host_data use_device` if it was not the case.

Comment: I could be wrong, but Isn't this expected given you've requested MPI create buffers across non-contiguous array segments?  ORDER_I uses array(idx,:,:) which causes an order of magnitude higher number of transfers than contiguous ORDER_K array(:,:,idx) given transfers can only be made in contiguous blocks.

Comment: Indeed, only face k is contiguous in memory, but a real world case may need to transfer non contiguous memory chunks. The manual approach shows that, even if the data is not contiguous, a contiguous buffer can be made on the GPU and copied in one transfer. I am wondering if a CUDA aware MPI implementation could do the same.